# Coldfusion jQuery find elements in dynamic divs

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, cfml

I have a dynamically created div that contains 2 divs.

```
<div style="background-color:##cccccc; font-weight:bold; padding:0px 2px 2px 2px;">Call List Notes</div>
    <div style="padding:2px 10px 5px 10px; ">
        <div id="clnoteformdivedit" style="display:none;">
            <cfform name="clnotefrm" action="" method="post">
                <cfinput type="hidden" name="ClIndNoteIndivnum" value="#val(attributes.UsersID)#">
                <cftextarea name="indNote" cols="60" rows="4">#qCallListNotes.notes#</cftextarea>
            <br />
            <cfinput type="button" name="CallListNotesButton" class="NotesButton" value="Submit Changes" />
            </cfform>
        </div>
        <div id="clnoteformdivdisplay">
                #qCallListNotes.notes#<br />
        </div>
    </div>
```

The idea is to just display the notes initially.  If the user clicks on that note/textarea that div is hidden and the div that allows input is shown. When they click on the submit button the data is updated, the edit div is hidden, and the display div is shown.

```
$('##CallListNotesButton').on('click', function() {
    var thisuserid = $(this).parent().find('##ClIndNoteIndivnum').val();
    var thisindivnote = $(this).parent().find('##indNote').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "actUpdateClIndivNote.cfm",
            data: 'calllistID=' + <cfoutput>#val(attributes.callListId)#</cfoutput> + '&userid=' + thisuserid + '&IndivNote=' + thisindivnote,
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // show error
            alert(errorThrown);
            },
            success: function(response1, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                //alert('success');
            $(this).parent().find('##indNote').val(thisindivnote);
            $('##clnoteformdivedit').hide();
            $('##clnoteformdivdisplay').show();
        }
        });
    });
    $('##clnoteformdivdisplay').on('click', function() {
        $('##clnoteformdivdisplay').hide();
        $('##clnoteformdivedit').show();
    });
```

The problem is displaying the updated notes in the display div. I can't find the correct div where I want to display the new notes.

Comment: for one thing, you have two #s in your jquery selectors

Comment: Coldfusion require them in pairs.  Only one is generated.

Comment: don't use `$(this)` inside `$.ajax` it isn't what you think it is. Pass in variable declaring element before the `$.ajax`

Comment: That's the problem. I was trying to find the updated value of indNote relaative to the div I'm in.